# Create Google like Numerical pin in ArcGIs

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, arcgis

All,

I have to add 200 markers on my arcgis map, however, I would like to label those markers with Pins having numbers in them. I was able to take Google's help in creating a numerical icon on the fly, but is it possible to achieve the same in ArcGis and without the use of Google or Bing Maps?

An Example of a numerical icon on the fly would be:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ff776b

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|ff776b

Thanks,

Comment: Does it have to be identical to Google's?  Can you use one of the markers that comes with ArcGIS instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create stacked labels with the default label manager in ArcGIS.  Although, like most other things in Arc it takes way too many steps to accomplish this.

1. Right-click on the layer in the `Table of Contents > Properties > Labels`.
2. Change the Label's Text sting to OBJECTID, FID, or any other attribute in your feature class that has a unique identifier (this is where the numbers will come from).
3. Next click on the `Symbol > Edit Symbol > Advanced Text > Check Text Background` and click Properties.
4. From the Properties window change the Type to Marker Text Background.
5. Click the Symbol button to change the background to a shape that meets your needs.
6. Click OK on all of the windows to get you back to your map.